# Store prime numbers into partial array

Tags: java

I'm trying to store all the prime numbers 1-100 into a partial array, and then print the result.

I need to have them in separate methods.

I think I figured out how to tell if a number is prime, but not how to return that number back to the main method to be store into an array.

Here's my code so far:

Main method:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
    int[] primeArray = new int[25];
    primeArray[0] =2;
    int numPrimes = 1;
    boolean prime;
    int currNumber;

    for(currNumber=3; currNumber<=100; currNumber++) {
        prime= isPrime(currNumber,primeArray,numPrimes);

        if(prime=true) {
            primeArray[numPrimes]=currNumber;
            numPrimes++;

            if (numPrimes==25)
                break;
        }

        System.out.println(primeArray[numPrimes]);
    }
}
```

isPrime method:

```
public static boolean isPrime (int currNum, int [] primeArray,int numPrimes) {  
    boolean prime=true;

    for(int i=0; i<numPrimes; i++) {
        if(currNumber/2%primeArray[i]==0)
            prime=false;
        break;
    }
    return prime;
} // end isPrime
```

Any advice would be appreciated; super confused right now.

Comment: Why do you need to "return the number back to the main method" if you already have it there in the form of `currNumber`?

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, but you might want to look into the Sieve of Eratosthenes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: I would change the `isPrime` signature as `public static boolean isPrime (int number)`.

Comment: Just a tip don't name your variables `prime` especially if they are `booleans` use things like:

`isPrime` that tells us the value of this variable can be either true / false.  Easier to read for other programmers.  If you kept it as `prime` someone could assume by glancing at your code that the value of `prime` is just that a prime number.

Comment: What do you mean by a "partial array"?

Answer (score 0):

A few things wrong with your code. In the main method, you are passing `currNum` in to the `isPrime()` method call. That variable doesn't exist, your code shouldn't compile. You want to pass `currNumber` into that method call. The second thing is your **if** statement is assigning the "prime" boolean to true, not checking it. It should just be `if(prime)`.

In your `isPrime()` method, you can add a `break;` in the prime check because if it's divisible by a number, it's not prime, no need to check the rest of the divisors:

```
    if(currNum%primeArray[i]==0) {
        prime = false;
        break;
    }
```

Since you are iterating through the prime array, the for loop should stop at the number of primes, not the current number:

```
for(int i=0; i<numPrimes; i++)
```

Comment: I would also added one more condition: `currNum / 2 <= primeArray[i]`. It doesn't make sense to check prime numbers that are greater than a half of current number.

Comment: I updated my code above.. it compiles fine but now I am getting an ArrayIndexOutofBounds error. I understand why, but not how to fix it.

Comment: Check the exception to find which line number you are getting that exception from. But without knowing that, I'd guess it's because your `primeArray[]` can only hold 25 int's, while there are more than 25 primes between 1 and 100. So either make that array larger or stop when you've found 25 primes.

Comment: That makes sense, I stopped it when I got 25 primes.

Now I want to print out the array, so I print out "System.out.print(primeArray[numPrimes]);"

Correct? I do this, but it just prints out all 0's.

Comment: You need to write some code to print out each of the primes in the array, System.out.print(primeArray[numPrimes]) isn't going to work.

Comment: Would you recommend just using a loop? I tried using the Arrays.toString(array) and it doesn't seem to do what I'm looking for. Should I use a loop? looping from 1-25?

Comment: Sorry, misread. You need to change that to `System.out.print(primeArray[numPrimes-1]);` because you've incremented numPrimes.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a pretty good job, I can see a couple of errors right away:

1. `if(prime=true)` should be `if(prime==true)` or for booleans you normally use only the expression, i.e. `if(prime)`
2. Check the loop where you check for primehood. x % 1 will always be 0 ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would change the `isPrime` signature as `public static boolean isPrime(int number)` and define it such that it would take a number and return true/false based on whether the number is prime or not.

```
public static boolean isPrime(int number) {
    if(number < 2) {
        return false;
    } else if(number < 4) {
        return true;
    }

    for(int i=2; i<=number/2; i++) {
        if(number % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: That seems easier, but this is the way that I was asked to do it.